# Changing image names programmatically to match their paths

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line, batch-processing

I have a directory which contains a number of folders.

```
Root Folder
   >directory
     >subdirectory
        >img
          image1.gif
     >subdirectory2
        >img
          image1.gif
   >directory2
     >img
        image1.gif
    ...
```

I would like for each image to have prepended its parent folders, with an "_" delimiter - up until the Root Folder, without prepending the "img" folder.

So, in our case it change the names of our images to :

```
Root Folder
   >directory
     >subdirectory
        >img
          directory_subdirectory_image1.gif
     >subdirectory2
        >img
          directory_subdirectory2_image1.gif
   >directory2
     >img
        directory2_image1.gif
```

And then, if possible, it would be much preferable if I could copy all of the images to one renamed folder.

I've tried using Renamer which will not work (does not allow for if statements so cannot skip images) :

[image]

And I'm trying to write a batch script to accomplish this, but having some troubles, specifically with the IF and getting all directories/sub-directories.

```
@echo off
pushd "Folder"
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      ren "%%F" "%%~nxP_%%~nxF"
    )
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

Can anyone help me in how to accomplish this please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for batch answers or powershell answers? This is the second time in recent history you have tagged powershell with batch content

Comment: @Matt since this is one off and I have been meaning to improve my knowledge of both, am I allowed to say that an answer in both would suit me down to the ground? Apologies if this is against some rule - will update accordingly if so :)

Comment: It's not against any rule per sei. Just want to be sure you are not wasting anyone's time is all. _Some_ questions tagged like this are people not looking for knowledge and just a quick answer. Those questions are not usually beneficial to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PowerShell answer. It is not an efficient use of the language but I wanted to present something that was easy to read. Change the `$rootPath` to the path where your `Root Folder` from your question.

```
$rootPath = "f:\temp"
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Filter *.gif -Recurse | ForEach-Object{
    $newnamePrefix = $_.DirectoryName -replace [regex]::escape("$rootPath\") -replace "\\","_"
    $newName = $newnamePrefix + "_" + $_.Name
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

This code is untested so try on a copy of your data. Uses the directory name of the file to build a `$newnamePrefix` which is then added to the current name. Again this could be made more efficient and simplified but it should give you an idea of what you can do.

**Shorter that handles the movement**

This is a shortened version of what happens above and it will move all the files into another directory as well as omit the `img` portion of the new name

```
$rootPath = "f:\temp"
$newPath = "F:\newdirectory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Filter *.gif -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName -replace "$([regex]::Escape("$RootPath"))\\(.*?)\\img(\\.*?\.gif)", '$1$2' -replace "\\","_"} -PassThru |
    Move-Item -Destination $newPath
```

Again, this is not tested.

Comment: Good answer, but he did ask to exclude the img folder in the rename. Try this modification: `-replace "$([regex]::Escape("$RootPath"))\\(.*?)\\img(\\.*?\.gif)", '$1$2' -replace "\\","_"` on the `$_.FullName` property

Comment: Thanks for the point @TheMadTechnician. Nice to know you are still around to correct me :)

Comment: @Matt Thank you guys so much for this, I've just spent the past little while trying to understand the code and it's really helpful. When I try to run it, however, I get the error "Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string. At C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Test\ttest.ps1:4 char:16
+     Rename-Item <<<<  ($_.FullName -replace "$([regex]::Escape("$RootPath"))\\(.*?)\\img(\\.*?\.gif)", '$1$2' -replac
e "\\","_") -PassThru |.

Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks so much again, will award bounty when the site will let me :).

Comment: Let me have another look at the code. Could have easily made a syntax error.

Comment: @Matt thank you very much, I'm still messing around with it but cannot figure out the cause for the issue. Thank you :)

Comment: @SimonKiely I changed the braces on `Rename-Item`. Seems to be working now. Let me know if you still have an issue.

Comment: @Matt Thanks so much for having a look at this again. It's actually a lot of fun to try and script with this :). Unfortunately at the moment when I try to run your script, it returns me this message multiple times in Powershell : http://i.imgur.com/9WhxxS3.png. 
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument:(C:/User/Desktop/Folder/imagen1.gif:PSObject) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException

It seems to return this for every image it parses. Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: @SimonKiely again. sorry about that one. I needed to specify the parameter `-destination` hopefully that is the end of your woes. If not we can start a chat maybe

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commented batch solution for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "RootFolder=C:\Temp\Test\"
set "ListFile=%TEMP%\FilesList.tmp"

rem Get list of all files in all subdirectories.
dir /A-D /B /ON /S "%RootFolder%">"%ListFile%" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 goto CleanUp

rem For each file in list file do the file rename.
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%F in ("%ListFile%") do call :RenameFile "%%F"

:CleanUp
del "%ListFile%"
goto :EOF

:RenameFile
rem The list file contains each file name with full path.
set "FileNameWithPath=%~1"

rem Get full path to file.
set "FilePath=%~dp1"

rem Remove the backslash at end of path.
set "FilePath=%FilePath:~0,-1%"

rem Get name of folder containing the file.
for /F "delims=" %%D in ("%FilePath%") do set "ImageFolder=%%~nD"

rem Remove the root folder path from file name with path.
set "NewFileName=!FileNameWithPath:%RootFolder%=!"

rem Remove the folder containing the file.
set "NewFileName=!NewFileName:\%ImageFolder%\=_!"

rem Replace all backslashes by underscores.
set "NewFileName=%NewFileName:\=_%"

rem Execute the file renaming operation.
ren "%FileNameWithPath%" "%NewFileName%"
goto :EOF
```

The value assigned to local environment variable **RootFolder** at top must be adapted to your root folder path. The backslash at end is important as otherwise all file names would start with an underscore after rename operation.

**Note:**

The result would be wrong if name of folder containing an image file exists twice in path, i.e.
`directory\img\subdirectory\img\image1.gif`
results in
`directory_subdirectory_image1.gif`
instead of
`directory_img_subdirectory_image1.gif`

Comment: thanks for this solution, I just ran it to test it and it seems to prepend the name of the parent folder on five times, so it is "_folder_folder_folder_folder_folder_img.gif". Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Well, I tested my batch code with exactly what you have posted in question and it produces exactly what you wanted. If you put `echo ` before `ren "%FileNameWithPath%" "%NewFileName%"` you can see the rename commands without being really executed. Other echo commands can be inserted in batch code to see what happens during execution. Or `echo off` at top is changed to `echo on`.